# Intepreting git log -all

Tags: git

When I do `git log -all`

I see commits such as:

```
commit 7327b7d27b5d9c7bb70be31b37cfa8cf6b29d282
Merge: 4f2782a ce130f4
Author: Bob <bob@rd.ie>
Date:   Tue Nov 19 17:37:07 2013 +0000

    Merge branch 'feature/angul' of tools:shop into feature/angul
```

My question:

The merge number: `4f2782a ce130f4`, why does git a merge number what does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special attribute of merge commits.
Whereas "normal" commits have only one predecessor, your merge commit has two, namely `4f2782a` and `ce130f4`.

You can visualize the situation with `git log --graph`